# Get Count of Each Distinct Pair

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to create a query that will give me all combinations of original sources and new sources, along with how many times each occur. What I have below seems to do the first part of giving me all of the different pairs, but I am struggling with getting it to display how many occurrences each have.

```
SELECT DISTINCT original_source, new_source
FROM sources
WHERE identifier = 1
ORDER BY original_source
```

Comment: Seems you need a `COUNT` not a `DISTINCT`.

Comment: Please add sample data.

Comment: ...and the expected result. I.e. a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT original_source, new_source, count(1) [Count]
FROM sources
WHERE identifier = 1
GROUP BY original_source, new_source
ORDER BY original_source
```

Comment: I'll upvote your answer, but it is considered bad form to post a virtually duplicate answer.